# Should we burninate unbalanced-classes tag and merge it with class-imbalance?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

Currently there are two tags for class imbalance, [class-imbalance](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-imbalance) and [unbalanced-classes](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unbalanced-classes).

Given that they refer to the exact same thing, and that the standard term in the literature is "*class imbalance*", should we burninate [unbalanced-classes](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unbalanced-classes) and re-tag the relevant questions as [class-imbalance](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-imbalance)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds reasonable. I went over the questions with the `unbalanced-classes` tag and agree they refer to the same thing. I'll go ahead and merge the two making `class-imbalance` the target tag.